# What is the correct syntax inside the src property in a img tag for a mapped json file using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want to import some images from a local JSON file to my component. I want them to match with the data that I fetch from the API.

My JSON file is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "dwarf": "/assets/races/dwarf.png",
    "slug": "dwarf"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "elf": "/assets/races/elf.png",
    "slug": "elf"
  }
]
```

I have this for mapping the JSON file:

```
                {images.map((item, index) => (
                    <C.Image
                        key={index}
                        item={item}
                    >
                        <img src={`item.${data.slug}`} />
                        <img src={item.dwarf} />
                    </C.Image>
```

`{data.slug}` is fetched from the API and matches the property name that I pass to each image inside the JSON file.
When I insert `<img src={item.dwarf} />`, I have the image displayed, but it is the same for all. When I insert `` <img src={`item.${data.slug}`} /> ``, the image is not displayed and at the console it shows `<img src="item.dwarf"> <img src="item.elf">`, instead of the image.
What is the syntax to make use of the `{data.slug}` replacing each name and displaying the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to dynamically access object properties. It looks like this:

```js
const obj = { foo: 123, bar: 321 }

const propName = 'foo'
const prop = obj[propName]

console.log(prop) // output: 123
```

So in your case:

```
<img src={item[item.slug]} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked! Instead of `<img src={item[item.slug]} />`, I inserted `<img src={item[data.slug]} />`. With `[item.slug]` all images where displayed together.  Using `[data.slug]` that I fetch from the API I was able to insert each image inside its respective place. Thanks again for the bracket notation tip. I appreciate it.